# Specify entity name while generating from existing database table symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I've a database table `users` and I want to generate its entity in my symfony2 bundle `KapCrudBundle`.

I'm using the following commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Kap/CrudBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --filter=Users

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import KapCrudBundle annotation --filter=Users

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities KapCrudBundle
```

These all above commands working absolutely fine but I want to do the following things:

1. It's generating the entity `Users.php` and annotation file `Users.orm.yml` because my table name is users but I want the entity name and annotation files like `User.php` and `User.orm.yml`
2. Second thing is that it generates all entities again in the bundle but I want only the User entity to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 2nd question: you can simply specify the entity.

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities KapCrudBundle/Entity/User
```